# netsh wlan command to connect new profile with known password

Tags: windows-8, netsh, wifi

I am using windows 8 to try to connect to wifi via cmd. Is there a netsh wlan command to connect to a new profile not configured in system?. Should we always add the network and then connect??
When we are using GUI to connect to a new profile, it simply prompts for a password. If the entered password is correct, it connects else it shows an error.